# Emacs cursor jumps to end of line in Tidal upon code execution

Tags: emacs, cursor

So I'm running this very niche live music coding program called Tidal which may be the only scope of this problem, however I was curious if this is a more broadly known behavior of Emacs, or Haskell.

`C-c C-c`, the shortcut to execute a line of code, causes the cursor to jump one line ahead, which really disrupts my workflow.

Comment: That wouldn't definitely be an editor issue and has nothing to do with Haskell.  My guess is that you have two bindings for `C-c C-c` assigned, and one of them is to skip ahead one line.

Comment: Are you using `tidal.el`? If so, it looks like `C-c C-c` is bound to the function `tidal-run-line`, and [the last statement in that function](https://github.com/yaxu/Tidal/blob/master/tidal.el#L155) is a call to `next-line`, try commenting that out.